# compile dlib and opencv with android ndk

Tags: android, build, android-ndk, dlib, android-studio-2.3

I am an android developer, but I am new to Android NDK, please help, or tell me what else would you need/ how would you try to solve this type of problem.

I used [this](https://github.com/tzutalin/dlib-android) dlib for android example and the official [opencv for android library](http://opencv.org/platforms/android/) and I would like to integrate the two in one application. When I trying to build the project I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':openCVSamplefacedetection:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process /home/feli/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/home/feli/Development/android/test/face-detection/openCVSamplefacedetection/src/main/jni/Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=/home/feli/Development/android/test/face-detection/openCVSamplefacedetection/src/main/jni/Application.mk APP_ABI=mips64 NDK_ALL_ABIS=mips64 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=/home/feli/Development/android/test/face-detection/openCVSamplefacedetection/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=/home/feli/Development/android/test/face-detection/openCVSamplefacedetection/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib /home/feli/Development/android/test/face-detection/openCVSamplefacedetection/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/mips64/libdetection_based_tracker.so}
  [mips64] Compile++      : detection_based_tracker <= DetectionBasedTracker_jni.cpp
  [mips64] Prebuilt       : libopencv_java3.so <= /home/feli/Android/openCV/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/mips64/
  [mips64] SharedLibrary  : libdetection_based_tracker.so
  /home/feli/Development/android/test/face-detection/openCVSamplefacedetection/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/mips64/objs-debug/detection_based_tracker/DetectionBasedTracker_jni.o: In function `dlib_check_consistent_assert_usage':
  /home/feli/Development/android/test/face-detection/openCVSamplefacedetection/src/main/jni/dlib/dlib/threads/threads_kernel_shared.h:44: undefined reference to `USER_ERROR__missing_dlib_all_source_cpp_file__OR__inconsistent_use_of_DEBUG_or_ENABLE_ASSERTS_preprocessor_directives_'
  clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  make: *** [/home/feli/Development/android/test/face-detection/openCVSamplefacedetection/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/mips64/libdetection_based_tracker.so] Error 1


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

My first guess were that I haven/t included the source.cpp in my Android.mk but placeing it to the src files didn't solve the porblem. 
Here is my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

## Build dlib to static library
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := dlib
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/dlib

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/dlib/dlib/all/source.cpp \
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/dlib//dlib/threads/threads_kernel_shared.cpp \
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/dlib/dlib/entropy_decoder/entropy_decoder_kernel_2.cpp \
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/dlib/dlib/base64/base64_kernel_1.cpp \
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/dlib/dlib/threads/threads_kernel_1.cpp \
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/dlib/dlib/threads/threads_kernel_2.cpp

LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_C_INCLUDES)
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

# Build opencv
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCVROOT := ~/Android/openCV/OpenCV-android-sdk
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE := SHARED
include ${OPENCVROOT}/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE     := detection_based_tracker
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := DetectionBasedTracker_jni.cpp

LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -lm -llog -ldl -lz -ljnigraphics
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions -frtti -std=c++11

# LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += dlib

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Maybe the `NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null` is the problem? Than why the two libraries are building separately? Or what else can be the problem? I tried a lot modifying the Android.mk, but it's working is a mystery for me. 
Any help or opinion would be useful.

**EDIT:**

When I comment out the `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += dlib` row, I got the following exception:

```
Build command failed.
  Error while executing process /home/feli/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/home/feli/Development/android/test/face-detection/openCVSamplefacedetection/src/main/jni/Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=/home/feli/Development/android/test/face-detection/openCVSamplefacedetection/src/main/jni/Application.mk APP_ABI=mips64 NDK_ALL_ABIS=mips64 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=/home/feli/Development/android/test/face-detection/openCVSamplefacedetection/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=/home/feli/Development/android/test/face-detection/openCVSamplefacedetection/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib /home/feli/Development/android/test/face-detection/openCVSamplefacedetection/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/mips64/libdetection_based_tracker.so}
  [mips64] Compile++      : detection_based_tracker <= DetectionBasedTracker_jni.cpp
  [mips64] Compile++      : dlib <= source.cpp
  In file included from /home/feli/Development/android/test/face-detection/openCVSamplefacedetection/src/main/jni/dlib/dlib/all/source.cpp:76:
  In file included from /home/feli/Development/android/test/face-detection/openCVSamplefacedetection/src/main/jni/dlib/dlib/all/../gui_widgets/fonts.cpp:14:
  /home/feli/Development/android/test/face-detection/openCVSamplefacedetection/src/main/jni/dlib/dlib/all/../gui_widgets/nativefont.h:27:10: fatal error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found
  #include <X11/Xlib.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  make: *** [/home/feli/Development/android/test/face-detection/openCVSamplefacedetection/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/mips64/objs-debug/dlib//home/feli/Development/android/test/face-detection/openCVSamplefacedetection/src/main/jni/dlib/dlib/all/source.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Do you really need MIPS build? If you intend to run your app on ARM devices, add **abiFilters= "armeabi_v7a"** to your **build.gradle** script.

Comment: I am running on abi arm64-v8a, but I am modifying the native c++ code also, so I suppose I need to build it also.

Comment: You should not comment out `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += dlib`

Comment: I have edited my question, please check it if you have time

Comment: I am suspicious about `NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null` in both error messages. Could that cause the problem? How could I set this variable?

Comment: No, you should not worry about `NDK_PROJECT_PATH`, that's how Android Studio configures the native build via **ndk-build**. But `dlib` is structured around **cmake**, so should reproduce the build settings used there.

Comment: Did you figure out how to use dlib on Android?

Comment: @AbhishekSoni no, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2):

`dlib` uses **cmake**, and it is not a trivial setup. It may take a long time for an experience professional to prepare the **ndk-build** scripts for this library.

I suggest that you build your native library with **cmake**, instead of **ndk-build**. You can find an example of a native library that uses OpenCv [on GitHub](https://github.com/leadrien/opencv_native_androidstudio).

Also, I suggest that you start with **abiFilters** set to only one most relevant ABI, and only when you see that everything works for you, you can build your project for other ABIs. Remember that for some libraries porting to all ABIs may be tricky. And if you don't have a platform to perform at least a brief sanity check for some ABI, there is no sense in building for it.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that!